# Angular sending null parameter. It shouldn't

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a filtering system and this part is responsible for finding items of specific status. The code below worked fine, but I had to change it to a select input as per request.

```
<ul id="dropdown-basic" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">
              <li role="menuitem"><a (click)="changeFilterStatus(null)" class="dropdown-item">Kõik</a></li>
              <li role="menuitem"><a (click)="changeFilterStatus('active')" class="dropdown-item">Aktiivne</a></li>
              <li role="menuitem"><a (click)="changeFilterStatus('temporarily_inactive')" class="dropdown-item">Ajutiselt peatatud</a></li>
              <li role="menuitem"><a (click)="changeFilterStatus('inactive')" class="dropdown-item">Mitteaktiivne</a></li>
            </ul>
```

The code below is giving me a hard time. The option with `[value]="null"` still sends an HTTP request to `url/clients?status=null` instead of `url/clients`. 
The code above worked fine, parameters are added if filters exist. In case of "null" the filter shouldn't be applied and show items of all statuses.

```
<select (change)="changeFilterStatus($event.target.value)" class="form-control">
                <option [value]="null">Kõik</option>
                <option [value]="'active'">Aktiivne</option>
                <option [value]="'temporarily_inactive'">Ajutiselt peatatud</option>
                <option [value]="'inactive'">Mitteaktiivne</option>
            </select>
```

This is the changeFilterStatus function

```
changeFilterStatus(status) {
    if (this.filterStatus !== status) {
      this.filterStatus = status;
      this.filter.status = status;
      this.getFilteredClients();
    }
  }
```

Comment: if (this.filterStatus != status)  try using this .. in your first code you were sending null now you are sending "null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:

```
changeFilterStatus(status) {
    if (status === 'null') {
      status = null;
    }
    if (this.filterStatus !== status) {
      this.filterStatus = status;
      this.filter.status = status;
      this.getFilteredClients();
    }
  }
```

I guess I had it in string form before, making it null worked. I have a filter that adds or removes parameters to/from the URL depending if they're null or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave an option value empty:

```html
<option [value]="">Kõik</option>
```

Comment: This sets value as "Kõik"

Comment: Well, then just check `status != null` in your functions

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just `null` check it ?

```
changeFilterStatus(status) {
    if (status && this.filterStatus !== status) {
      this.filterStatus = status;
      this.filter.status = status;
      this.getFilteredClients();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I still have to send the null though, that's how it knows what to return.

Answer (score 0):

If `status` is null do not send the `status` parameter

You could do something like

```
changeFilterStatus(status) {
  // Status is null
  if(!status) { \\ Call the url as it is without status }
  else { \\ Call the url passing the status }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngModel

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="changeFilterStatus(selectedValue)" class="form-control">
                <option [value]="null">Kõik</option>
                <option [value]="'active'">Aktiivne</option>
                <option [value]="'temporarily_inactive'">Ajutiselt peatatud</option>
                <option [value]="'inactive'">Mitteaktiivne</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your web service:

```
import { Http, 
         Headers,
         RequestMethod,
         RequestOptionsArgs,
         Response }           from '@angular/http';
...
  webServiceCall(status) : Observable<Response> {
     if (len(status) > 0) { // Or status === "null" - I would change it to "" in markup too.
        let options:RequestOptionsArgs = {
           search : encodeParams(status);
        }
        result = this.http.request(url,options);
      } else {
        result = this.http.request(ur);
    return  result
  }
```

The other answers will likely result in an HTTP500 because of `url/clients?status=`